# Почему typescript не реагирует на тип при использование promise?

Tags: typescript, типы, typescript-типы

Я записала в переменную string значение number, и не получаю ошибки почему так происходит?

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-elgamal-4lbin2

```
const BEApi = new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve({
    string: 123
  });
});
type MyDataType = {
  string: string;
};

let myData: MyDataType | null = null;

const myResponce = async () => {
  myData = (await BEApi) as MyDataType;
  console.log(myData);
};

myResponce();
```

Comment: Потому что `BEApi` имеет тип `Promise<unknown>` (а вот почему он имеет такой тип, не знаю)

Comment: Потому что TS не настолько умный что бы вывести тип из вызова `resolve`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript не настолько умный что бы вывести тип из вызова функции `resolve`.

Варианты:

1. явно указать тип (`new Promise<MyDataType>...`), тогда TS сможет проверить что вызовы `resolve` соответствуют этому типу;
2. использовать статический метод `Promise.resolve`, тогда TS может вывести тип возвращаемого значения (в вашем тривиальном примере).

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ZQQY4wYLRZLfVeQA)

```typescript
type MyDataType = {
  string: string;
};

// Вариант 1
const BEApi1 = new Promise<MyDataType>((resolve) => {
  resolve({
    string: 123
  });
});

// Вариант 2
const BEApi2 = Promise.resolve({
  string: 123
});

let myData: MyDataType | null = null;

const myResponse = async () => {
  myData = await BEApi1;
  myData = await BEApi2;

  console.log(myData);
};

myResponse();
```